# Unexpected regex result using word boundary and asterisk character

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am testing some regex patterns for a project I'm working on.
In one of the patterns I am trying to match the input `"f**"` and `"f**xxx"` meaning literally "f**" followed by any number of non white space characters with a word boundary.
This is the regex I came up with:

```
\bf\*\*[^\s]*\b
```

It does match `"f**xxx"` but it doesn't match `"f**"` nor `"f***"`. For some reason the input string cannot end with an asterisk. Is there anything I'm missing?

I did some further testing and if I remove the last word boundary `\bf\*\*[^\s]*` it works (but I need it). Also, if instead of an asterisk the character is, for example, an underscore, the pattern works.

So pattern:

```
\bf\_\_[^\s]*\b
```

Matches input `"f__"` (f + 2 underscores) `"f___"` (f + 3 underscores) and `"f__xxx"` (f + 2 underscores + xxx)

I tested these regex on the site regex101 with flavour PCRE2 PHP>=7.3. And the same thing happens in my project which runs hyperscan and RE2 in C++.

Comment: `\bf\*\*[^\s]*\b` will match `f***` only if there is a word char right after. Only use the word boundary if you expect it. Or, use the adaptive word boundary, `(?!\B\w)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/FfJfHG/2)). It won't work in RE2 though since it does not  support lookarounds. Then use common workarounds like `(?:\s|$)` or `(?:\W|$)`.

Comment: The pattern is for f-star-star then any amount of spaces, then a word boundary. But the string `"f**` is not that - it's just f-star-star and there is no other word characters after the stars. Thus no word boundary. You might need to revise *what* you need to match.

Comment: It turns out I didn't quite understand what a word boundary meant. Now that I do I can totally see why my regex wouldn't match. I'll test with the boundaries you, @WiktorStribiżew gave me, and see if that works.

Otherwise I'll just remove the word boundary when what I want to match doesn't end with a word boundary. Thanks for the help :)